# How to customize popover to be the same width of its ion-select

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have a problem with ion-select component which is the width of it's popover items. it doesn't match the size of it's parent ion-select.

I tried to fix this issue by using onclick event as below:

> [(ngModel)]="value" [id]="id" class="ps-select" [okText]="okText"       [cancelText]="cancelText" [multiple]="false"
>   [interface]="popover" [placeholder]="placeHolderTrans">
>                   
>                       {{ item.description }}

ts file:

> onClick(event){
>        this.divwidth = event.srcElement.clientWidth;
>        this.cssclass = document.querySelector('.popover-content') as HTMLElement;
>        console.log("sudfasu",this.divwidth) ; 
>        this.cssclass.style.width = this.divwidth;  }

but when I try to catch the div with class "popover-content"
I always got an error of 'Cannot read property 'style' of null'

can anyone help me with this problem or if there's another way to set popover list items width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to assign popover width by using Css variables, defined it in app.scss
and assigned them in my ts file

in app.scss

> :popwidth {    --width: 0px;    }
>
> [dir="ltr"] .select-popover .popover-content{      width: var(--width); 
>   }

file.ts

> onClick(event){
>       this.divwidth = event.srcElement.clientWidth;
>       let popwidth = document.documentElement;
>       popwidth.style.setProperty('--width',  this.divwidth + "px");
>     }